# Invalid session token on request

Tags: php, request

I've been using [REQUEST](http://requests.ryanmccue.info/) on my project. what i want to achieve is to populate our data to this site [website](https://online.immi.gov.au/lusc/login) . the site needs authentication before we could create or post the data. here is my code

```
function submit_immi(){

$this->load->library(array('PHPRequests'));

$options = array(
        'auth' => new Requests_Auth_Basic(array('myusername', 'mypassword'))
    );      

    $response = Requests::post('https://online.immi.gov.au/ola/app', array(), $options);       

    var_dump($response->body);
```

}

this is the result

> string(5578) " ]> ImmiAccountLogin to ImmiAccountFields marked * must be completed.UsernamejoserespallPasswordLoginCancelI have forgotten my ImmiAccountusername or password
>   Create an ImmiAccountCreate an ImmiAccount to access the Department of Immigration and Border Protection's online services.Create ImmiAccountAccessibilityCopyright & DisclaimerOnline SecurityPrivacy"

I've been approaching it in different methods until i got a different response. my code

```
function submit_immi(){
    $this->load->library(array('PHPRequests'));

    $data = array(
        '_2b0a0a0d0b0'  =>  'username',
        '_2b0a0a0d1b0'  =>  'password'
    );

    $response = Requests::get('https://online.immi.gov.au/lusc/login',array(),$data);

    preg_match_all('/value="([^\"]+)/',$response->body,$match);

    $wc_s = $match[1][0];
    $wc_t = $match[1][1];

    $response = Requests::post("https://online.immi.gov.au/lusc/login?wc_s=$wc_s&wc_t=$wc_t",array(),$data);

    var_dump($response->body);
}
```

this is what it shows

> string(2362) " ]> Manage my ImmiAccount Invalid session token on request. Accessibility Copyright & Disclaimer Online Security Privacy "

Am i doing it wrong? Can someone point me on the right path?

Thank you.